# How to change mili second format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to insert to mysql with datetype colunm

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

I want to insert date and time to `post_date` column in Wordpress. The column data type is `datetime yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. I want to generate first row is: 2015-01-01 01:01:01 and add 60 seconds to the next row 2015-01-01 01:02:01.

I found this code but I don't know how to convert millisecond to second format. It's print 2015-11-22 15:41:29.496, but how to get rid of ".496"? Is my data type when I insert to MySQL was formatted like: datetime? will wordpress understand it?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

long retryDate = System.currentTimeMillis();

int sec = 60;

Timestamp original = new Timestamp(retryDate);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(original.getTime());
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
Timestamp later = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());

System.out.println(original);
System.out.println(later);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)` to clear the milliseconds.
Use `new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis())` to get as `Timestamp`.

```
final int sec = 60;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Timestamp original = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());

cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
Timestamp later = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());

System.out.println(original);
System.out.println(later);
```

Java 8 version using [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html):

```
final int sec = 60;

Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
Timestamp original = Timestamp.from(instant);

instant = instant.plusSeconds(sec);
Timestamp later = Timestamp.from(instant);

System.out.println(original);
System.out.println(later);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use formatter to format datetime

```
public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date now = new Date();
    String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
    return strDate;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't provide a `Timestamp` for use with `PreparedStatement`. It does provide a String for use with string concatenation to build a SQL statement, susceptible to syntax errors and [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, the latter of which allows hackers to steal and/or delete your data.